# How to convert a string to utf-8 code in php

Tags: php

i need a function or a simple algo to help me convert a normal string to utf-8 code

ex: 
string:

```
hello
عربي
```

UTF-8 CODE:

```
68 65 6C 6C 6F 0A 0639 0631 0628 064A 0A
```

Comment: Try `iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);`

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or

Comment: iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);               helpful link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or

Answer (score 12):

use the  **utf8_encode (  $data )**

see its full documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: utf8_encode ( $data ) Work only on ISO-8859-1 code .
as I see in the question , the text probably are in "windows-1256" code the easiest way is 
`iconv("windows-1256","utf-8",$txt);`

Answer (score 11):

Use `iconv`, as shown:

```
$text = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);
```

This is also detects the strings current character set.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `iconv` funcion [here is description](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use it with arabic

you can use arabic php library at : http://ar-php.org/

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
...
$somStr = 'Hello';
utf8_encode_deep($somStr); // Converting string to utf8
print_r($somStr);
...
```

For more details regarding `utf8_encode_deep()` see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Hope it solves this problem.