# php String iteration does not detect Π symbol

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have string in PHP "S*+%2YKΠ3)3Π+)+Θ" that I want to iterate.

my code :

```
$string = "S*+%2YKΠ3)3Π+)+Θ";
$charLength = mb_strlen($string);
for($i = 0 ; $i < $charLength ; $i++) {
    $char = mb_substr($string, $i , 1);
    if($char == 'Π') {
       echo "this is my Π character";
    }
}
```

But I never entering the echo statement to get "this is my Π character",

Anyone to help me with this problem, please ...
I already looking for others answer like:

[How to convert any character encoding to UTF8 on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559822/how-to-convert-any-character-encoding-to-utf8-on-php)

[Convert utf8-characters to iso-88591 and back in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374425/convert-utf8-characters-to-iso-88591-and-back-in-php)

[PHP: Convert any string to UTF-8 without knowing the original character set, or at least try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or)

[How to convert a string to utf-8 code in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342204/how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8-code-in-php)

but never work for my case. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as such is fine, however there are a number of possible pitfalls:

1. You need to tell the `mb` functions what encoding they're supposed to work on. Either pass the encoding to each one individually (e.g. `mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8')`), or set the encoding once for all using [`mb_internal_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_internal_encoding).
2. Your .php source code file must be saved in UTF-8 if you want your string literals to be UTF-8 encoded. Check in your text editor of choice that you're actually saving the file encoded as UTF-8 (no BOM).

Comment: Thanks! i added mb_substr($string, $i , 1, 'UTF-8') and worked well!