# Mediawiki mass-upload breaks the page

Tags: mediawiki

Related question: [Mass-upload many text files to MediaWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151825/mass-upload-many-text-files-to-mediawiki/)

I used shell script and ImportTextFile.php as Ilmari Karonen told me.

But the result is a broken page like

��{�{�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|� �m�a�z�i�n�g�a�*�m�i�r�a�c�l�e� �=� �1� � �|� �a�p�p�l�e�*�c�o�m�p�u�t�e�r� �=� �j�o�b�s� � �|�

The actual content goes like

```
{{miracle
| mazinga_miracle = 1
| apple_computer = jobs
| mazinga_miracle = 1
| apple_computer = jobs
| mazinga_miracle = 1
| apple_computer = jobs
| mazinga_miracle = 1
| apple_computer = jobs
| mazinga_miracle = 1
| apple_computer = jobs
| mazinga_miracle = 1
```

So the program inserts "�" for every bit of string.

What's the problem?

Ah! I got the answer. After I change this to UTF-8, no problem! :)

Answer (score 2):

Ah! I got the answer. After I change this to UTF-8, no problem! :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Anatoliy_Nikolaev ?? Perhaps you're confused a bit? This finding (that the problem of broken page from mediawiki upload using importtextfile.php can be fixed by changing the file to utf-8) is from "me". Perhaps many people already know this. But anyhow I found this solution by myself. So there's no answer that I can "vote up".

Comment: @Tala Why do you think this doesn't provide an answer? This solution is simple and short, but it indeed solves the problem. I thought posting this solution could help many complete novices like me.