# PHP curl - having a bit of trouble with special/unique/rare characters

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code on my server running on php 5.2.*;

```
$curl = curl_init();
//$sumName = curl_escape($curl, $sumNameWeb);
$summonerName = urlencode($summonerName);
$url = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/{$summonerName}?api_key=".$key;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$result = utf8_encode($result);
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
```

It works fine, however when it comes to special characters like; ë Ö å í .. etc it fails to connect.. I have been trying different ways maybe i would find a fix but i am failing to do so..

ok i have found my error!! however this is my situation.. it is connecting to the server and getting the data.. AND i am using $sumNameWeb to access the JSON when it is decoded however the returned $sumNameWeb special character has changed.. here is the code to access the JSON;

```
$sumID =  $obj[$sumNameWeb]["id"];
$sumLvl = $obj[$sumNameWeb]["summonerLevel"];
```

an example is, entering ë and returning Ã« from the server

Comment: Check this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

Try to set one more curl parameter into your curl request that filters garbage data from result.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
```

I hope this helps you!!

Comment: the data is being returned as a JSON

Comment: @Joseph118  Oh i see.

Comment: Thank for help, After adding this I am getting fully html.

Answer (score 0):

[`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) encode non-ASCII characters according to the `UTF-8` charset encoding. So most likely your problem is that your text (source code) is in other encoding (different from `UTF-8`). You have to ensure it has `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: i have been looking into the api and i have found this.. Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8

Comment: I've already pointed you the source of the problem. You have to ensure the string you passed to `urlencode` (`$summonerName`) has `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Add [header](http://php.net/header) in the page before any sending curl.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. urlencode would not work with these links. I had to specifically replace them my self.

```
$curl = curl_init();
//$sumName = curl_escape($curl, $sumNameWeb);
$summonerName = urlencode($summonerName);
$url = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/{$summonerName}?api_key=".$key;

$str = $url;
$str = str_replace("{", "%7B", $str);
$str = str_replace("$", "%24", $str);
$str = str_replace("}", "%7D", $str);
$url = $str;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$result = utf8_encode($result);
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
```

this should work. If additional characters need to be replaced you can find out their link substitute by following this link: [url encoder](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php)