# Mysql query keyword changes to unknown character set in php in case of Mobile devices

Tags: php, mysql, sql, jquery-mobile, zend-framework

I am using a search query for selecting names in my DB by giving a keyword.
My query is

```
SELECT `engine4_core_search`.* FROM `engine4_core_search` WHERE ((`engine4_core_search`.`title` LIKE "%".$text."%"))
```

When give " cardiff " (cardiff comes in place of $text ) as my keyword and checking the query ..it displays like

```
SELECT `engine4_core_search`.* FROM `engine4_core_search` WHERE ((`engine4_core_search`.`title` LIKE  'Êrdiff%'))
```

Is there any method to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So find out why there is unknown symbol in front of your string. What you pass - that you see.

Comment: @Justinas what ever keyword i pass , it will be replaced to unknown character set.Thats what i dint get any idea.

Comment: Have you tried converting encoding to `UTF-8` or whatever encoding your DB uses.

Comment: look at this maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you have included `jQuery-mobile` (because tagged in it)
In some cases `jQuery-mobile` replaces some strings when they attached with different patterns like " %cardiff " . It may considers to be different string set
Just remove `jQuery-mobile` and try for your output......

Comment: Thank you...Its worked fine when i remove jQuery-moile