# convert latin1_swedish_ci to utf8

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I am importing data from an xml, and it appears they use " latin1_swedish_ci" which is causing me lots of issues with php and mysql (PDO).

I'm getting a lot of these errors:

```
General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

I am wondering how I can convert them to proper UTF-8 to store in my database.

I've tried doing this:

```
        $game['human_name'] = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($game['human_name'], mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $game['human_name']);
```

Which I found here: [PHP: Convert any string to UTF-8 without knowing the original character set, or at least try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or)

I still seem to get the same error though?

Comment: Whats the collation of the table and its columns you are trying to insert into?

Comment: It's under "utf8_general_ci"

Comment: Have you tried forcing your PDO instance to use UTF-8? db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');

Comment: I also suggest trying 'mb_convert_encoding' instead of 'iconv' for your encoding function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any conversion functions -- get utf8 specified throughout the processing.

Make sure the data is encoded utf8.

When using PDO:

```
$db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pwd);
```

Table definitions (or at least columns):

```
CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Web page output:

```
<meta ... charset=UTF-8>
```