# MySQL "Incorrect String Value" Error with utf8mb4 encoding

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having a problem inserting some data into a varchar field of an InnoDB MySQL table with a PHP script.  Initially I thought the problem was caused by using utf8 character encoding because I did some research on the error I was getting, "Incorrect String Value" and found a couple of helpful posts here about switching my tables over to utf8mb4.

So I switched it to 'utf8mb4'.  I did this in a couple of different places, in the server settings, the table settings, the database settings, and also in php via mysqli_set_charset.  I also tried changing the MySQL setting 'character-set-client-handshake' to see if that would make a difference, but I still got the error even after restarting the MySQL server.

I decided that I would see if my PHP script was the problem so I opened up MySQL Workbench and entered the same query there.   Success!

So, now I am really puzzled.  Why can I run the query in MySQL workbench but not via PHP?  Here is my code.

In MySQL Workbench, this query works:

```
UPDATE books SET notes = 'Renâe Boivin, jeweller by Cailles, Franðcoise'  
WHERE asin LIKE '0704370905'
```

This is my PHP code for running that same query:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8mb4');
$sql = "UPDATE books SET notes = 'Renâe Boivin, jeweller by Cailles,   
Franðcoise' WHERE asin
LIKE '0704370905'";
```

That code generates this error:

`"Error: Incorrect string value: '\xE2e Boi...' for column 'notes' at row 2"`

Any ideas?  Maybe I'm just overlooking something really simple.  I appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you!

Comment: What's the character encoding of your PHP file? It'll depend on your editor, but typically (a) under the File menu somewhere, or when you save a file, you'll be able to specify the encoding, and (b) you'll want to use UTF-8, unless there's a very good reason not to. (Your problem is almost certainly that you're not actually sending UTF-8 data to the server because your query isn't saved in UTF-8 in the PHP file itself. MySQL Workbench will be using UTF-8.)

Comment: Thank you Matt!!  Sorry it took me so long to reply.  I found the File Encoding setting under the File menu in the editor I'm using (PHP Storm) and it allowed me to convert it to UTF-8.  I also was able to do this on the data file that I was trying to process, and this fixed all of the error messages.  Yay!  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. I've added a real answer now we've confirmed that that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have text in SQL embedded in a PHP file, the encoding of the PHP file itself comes into play. You need to make sure that your PHP file itself is saved in UTF-8. How you do that depends on your editor. For PHP it's also important to choose the "without BOM" (Byte Order Mark) option when saving a unicode file.

Answer (score -2):

Try forcing MySQL to only accept utf8 by using

`mysqli_set_charset('utf8');`

Then you can try brute-forcing PHP into utf-8

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

As well as ensuring the string you are sending is of utf-8 encoding. There are many previous StackOverflow questions to do this:
[PHP: Convert any string to UTF-8 without knowing the original character set, or at least try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or)