# php gets haywire and thinks that 1 is not equal 1

Tags: php

I have a variable which value is supposed to be 'age'. I checked if the value of this variable is equal or not to 'age'. Result is not equal.

```
echo $this->param;  // returns 'age'

if('age' == $this->param) echo 'equal';  // returns false
```

It inputs only the text 'age'. Where is 'equal'?

What is going on?

Comment: post output of `var_dump($this->param)` please

Comment: Can you `var_dump($this->param)`?

Comment: `var_dump($age, $this->param)`. you'll probably find that param is `age[space]` or something.

Comment: Sometimes there is non meaningful broken utf-8 chars exist, when you try to print it doesn't show up but languages detects that when checking equality or any other process.

Comment: var_dump($this->param) returns string(9) "age" hmm..?

Comment: Then you might have spaces, try to `trim()` before comparing

Comment: Try `if('age' == trim($this->param)) echo 'equal';`

Comment: If it returned `false` too then post output of `var_dump(trim($this->param))` to check if the issue is trimming or encoding.

Comment: The same result, returns string(9) "age".

Comment: Weird! Check this to change encoding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or and try to compare again

Comment: If it is string(9), you have got some leading/trailing whitespaces. trim () it.