# storing and displaying in UTF-8 MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I want to store all the data in UTF-8 so before storing
the input variables are converted to UTF-8 using 
`htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`
And then the database charset is set to UTF-8 and each table has the collation `utf8_general_ci`
However, When I store them, they all get saved as

```
Testing&amp;amp;lt;ASC&amp;amp;#039;a&amp;amp;#039;sc&amp;amp;#039;/A&amp;amp;gt;
```

And are displayed as such.
I removed `htmlspecialchars` function when I fetched the results.
But I still don't understand why it gets saved like that, I tried removing `htmlspecialchars` in the `$_POST` variables and then it saves it okay but then it comes out as HTML. For example if you fetched

```
<script>alert('lol')</script>
```

Which is not dangerous.

```
public function __construct() {
        $protected = array("_GET", "_POST", "_SERVER", "_COOKIE", "_FILES", "_ENV", "GLOBALS");
        foreach($protected as $var)
        {
            if(isset($_POST[$var]) || isset($_GET[$var]) || isset($_COOKIE[$var]) || isset($_FILES[$var]))
            {
                die("Hacking attempt");
            }
        }
        $this->strip_slashes_array($_REQUEST);
        $this->parse_incoming($_REQUEST);
    }

    public function parse_incoming($array) {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(!is_array($value)) {
                $this->input[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    function strip_slashes_array(&$array)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $val)
        {

                if(is_array($array[$key]))
        {
            $this->strip_slashes_array($array[$key]);
        }
        else
        {
            $array[$key] = htmlspecialchars($array[$key], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }

        }
    }
```

and when I insert them I use
`$class->input['key']` instead of `$_POST['key']`

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or

Comment: [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) doesn't convert to UTF-8. It does exactly what you got.

Comment: ohh, so what do i do in this case, i dont even need to convert it then.
I just want it to be displayed as its written without being converted into &amp........
The thing is that, it worked before, but i doesnt work now that the db collation is changed.

Comment: Seems you used `htmlspecialchars` on `Testing<ASC'a'sc'/A>` three times. You only need to call `htmlspecialchars` when you are rendering the HTML code. Also [`collation`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html) just determines how values are sorted not how they are stored.

Comment: Oh, Thank you guys,
I fixed this by changing
$this->strip_slashes_array($_REQUEST) to $requests = $_REQUEST
$this->strip_slashes_array($requests) 
And for some reason it is working

I tried to find the reason, it turned out that using $_REQUEST directly in the function returns the same result 4 times *(4x in the array) but i have no idea why.

Comment: You should not have to strip_slashes either.  Something is messing things up!

Comment: Please provide `bin2hex(...)` so we can see exactly what is in the string that you think needs fixing.