# PHP How to Remove/Replace Unknown question mark diamond characters

Tags: php

I am using PHP to access data on old machines and output them.

Putty shows:

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒NONE.
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

Its the weird formatting in a attempt to show data in a more clean way

PHP echo-ed chrome shows:

```
������
�NONE. �
������
```

I have tried:

```
$Str1 = str_replace("▒","",$Str1);
```

But it doesn't filter them out.
The output is already utf 8.

Does anyone know how to filter out these things? Maybe identify what � is to php?

Comment: Figure out what the actual *byte value* is, possibly convert the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Convert any string to UTF-8 without knowing the original character set, or at least try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or)

Comment: So its utf 8 already. I could try to find the byte value but I am not even sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Str1 = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $Str1);
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly. but why \x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF?

Comment: its remove unwanted character from string

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me too, how did you specifically know to use '/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/' ? Do you have docs you could link to?

Comment: it also removes other letters like ç, ğ

Comment: @temirbek exactly, therefore, this is not a valid solution

Comment: Thank you. Finally I can sleep now :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with a regex like `'/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/'` is that it simply demolishes ***all UTF-8***.  So, about only 1% or less of all possible characters will work with this.  [**Full Working Demo**](https://3v4l.org/LqkmR)

#### Why not prevent what is causing this?

With a fully utf-8-configured DB and proper headers, this problem can happen if you use:

- `substr()` — Instead, use [`mb_substr($utfstring, 0, 10, 'utf-8');`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).
- `htmlspecialchars()` — Instead, use [`htmlspecialchars($utfstring, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).
- `preg_replace()` — Instead, use [`mb_ereg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php).