# Squares apperaing in text, want to search & replace

Tags: php

I have a site where a client has inserted text. Probably by copying it from a PDF or Word document.
There is a strange character that appears at random places in the inserted text.
The site is full of them so i would like to get rid of them programmatically, either by a search and replace in the database or by filtering via PHP when the value is printed out via str_replace();

The character looks like this, and is not recognized when i search for it in the database, and not even when you search for it with the built in browser search function.

[image]

It looks the same in the database as it does when rendered. In some cases it´s like an empty square, in some cases with a questionmark inside it.

I have tried this without luck:

```
$value = str_replace( '', '',  $value );
```

(The square in first argument seems to be removed when i save)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP How to Remove/Replace Unknown question mark diamond characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541587/php-how-to-remove-replace-unknown-question-mark-diamond-characters)

Comment: `preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $value);`