# Special character input returns blank string

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8, special-characters, iconv

I have an app with an input field where you input your name. The app outputs the name on a pdf document with FPDF. As this app is in swedish, many people will input names with special character like å, ä, ö. The input looks like this:

```
$name = sanitize_text_field(base64_decode($_POST['name']));
```

And then to:

```
$specialCharacterName = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $name);
```

It then outputs to FPDF like this:

```
$pdf->Cell(265,30,' '.$specialCharacterName,0,1,'L',1);
```

The problem is, as soon as I input a name with a special character, like Björn for example, the output will be blank. But when I input a name without a special character, like Anders, it displays fine.

The strange thing is that when I don't use a variable, and input a string with a special character like this:

```
$specialCharacterName = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', 'Björn');
```

It works fine. The special character is outputted just fine in the PDF document. So there must be something wrong with the variable.

I have also tried utf8_encode() and the result is the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you inputing base64 encoded names? if not, why the `base64_decode()`?

Comment: This app is not made by me. I just edit it to fit my own preferences. I don't know why the original creator uses base64_decode(). I guess its for safety purposes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or

Comment: I checked the database and the special characters do not even get that far. So they are lost before they even get to the ($_POST['name'] it seems.

I have also tried adding accept-charset="UTF-8" in the form but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: I have noted that the form input goes through a $.ajax() function. I tried adding contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" but that didn't seem to do anything.