How do I convert an unknown Oracle character in data using PHP
How would I convert an unknown character when reading data from Oracle 19c database with a character set of AL32UTF8 and UTF8 using PHP 8?
As an expample, consider a character that appears in plain text as a long em dash, PHP array shows it as a "?" (see attached screenshot). When the JSON data is echoed to a PDF document, JSON fails to convert it. If I can determine the character, I can either replace it or convert it.
"TU – TP"


The character is not available at some point of the chain (that is, there is no way of representing it and it's lost). First, check the character set of your client session (the NLS_LANG environment variable). Are you running a PHP program against an Oracle DB, and creating the PDF from inside this program? What's the role of JSON?

Oracle 9i - Really? It is older than 20 years. I am surprised that you are able to connect at all.

Thanks for pointing that out, Wernfried. I meant to put 19c.

Diego, there are two separate queries for two separate areas; both use the same data field with the unknown character. One query generates physical PDFs, the other returns results for a website. The latter using JSON. My goal is to deal with the data upstream. So, basically, both fail due to this character. I am using PDO over Oracle DB with charset=latin1 in connection string. My PHP runs on Windows IIS.

I found a solution by Jeff Day. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7980354/2288547. iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);

I think the Oracle SQL*net layer may be converting from the DB charset (UTF8) to that of the client (Windows 1252 or UTF-16). Now you found a way of converting it back to UTF8 in your PHP code. If it works, it works. These things are tricky.

May be related to the fact that the long em dash uses three bytes in UTF-8.
